# Calculating acceleration of end point of rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Suppose I have a rod hinged at its end, of length $\ell$ free to rotate about an horizontal axis; initially in the horizontal position and I have to calculate the acceleration of its other end point. I know the derivation using torque but what if I consider the free body diagram of the end point. Two forces, gravity and tension act on it but since tension can only act in the horizontal direction only gravitational force acts in the vertical direction and hence its acceleration is $g$(in the downward direction), which is incorrect. What is wrong in this? Which force is responsible for increasing its acceleration to $3g/2$?

Comment: The line of action of the tension force is along the rod. There must be a force producing the centripetal acceleration of the particles which make up the rod.

Comment: Even when the angular velocity is zero? (I only wanted to know the vertical component of the acceleration though).

Comment: The hinge point can act in two directions, both horizontally and vertically. Why do you assume the reaction is only horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

The other parts of the rod exerts a tangential force on the end which contributes to its downward acceleration.  If you get a chance to watch a video of a tall brick chimney being demolished, notice that it breaks before hitting the ground.  It is not designed to withstand the lateral forces required to match the angular acceleration of the upper end with that of the lower sections.

Answer (score 0):

The component of $mg$ force, ($mgcos\theta$) will be equal to tension in the rod ( if string is inextensible, and $\theta$ is the angle of string with vertical) and therefore only $mgsin\theta$ will be left, which is responsible for restoring force in the string. And by dividing restoring force by  its mass, you can calculate its acceleration.

**EDIT**
In case of hinged rod, the same direction of tension and $mg$ force will be there, but they will act at Centre of mass of Rod, so again the formula for calculating acceleration will be same.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a string, just a hinged rod.

Comment: I have edited it @PM 2Ring

Comment: But what is wrong with my reasoning? I analysed only the end point not the entire rod.

Comment: Please do note that, Tension always has a pulling effect on body, so it will act along the axis of rod, not in horizontal direction

Comment: I assumed the rod to be in the horizontal direction and the axis I was talking about was the axis about which the rod is rotating.

Comment: Please add a diagram to your question for clarity

Comment: @sawankumawat random is right initially tension will be acting horizontal so it cant contribute to downward acceleration later on it might but initially it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

> Two forces, gravity and tension act on it but since tension can only act in the horizontal direction only gravitational force acts in the vertical direction and hence its acceleration is g

You are missing a major force called the hinge reaction . I've drawn it

- you can yourself check that your fbd must be wrong because in your case there is only one horizontal force on rod which is tension which makes it unstable (I.e there must be an accelerationin x direction). So there has to be a horizontal force balancing it and this force is provided by hinge
- similarly there is a normal hinge reaction in y direction too since you know acceleration is 3g/2 the hinge reaction must be in negative y direction . Here I've taken it in +y but on balancing forces you'll get it negative

[image]